# The javapackager is unable to generate a dmg on macOS

Tags: java, macos, terminal, dmg, javapackager

I am trying to generate a dmg from a jar using the javapackager.

Here is what I put into terminal:

```
cd "/Users/name/Documents/JarToApplication"
jdk=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
$jdk/bin/javapackager -deploy -native dmg -BappVersion=8 -name DMSLauncher -srcdir . -srcfiles DMSLauncher.jar -appclass com.blockhead7360.dms.launcher.DMSLauncher -Bicon=package/macosx/DMSLauncher.icns -outdir deploy -outfile DMSLauncher -v
```

And it runs until here:

```
Running [osascript, /var/folders/z5/n802xjnx49l4535kq63992280000gn/T/fxbundler8419176091447096668/macosx/DMSLauncher-dmg-setup.scpt]
/var/folders/z5/n802xjnx49l4535kq63992280000gn/T/fxbundler8419176091447096668/macosx/DMSLauncher-dmg-setup.scpt:635:742: execution error: Finder got an error: The operation can’t be completed because there is already an item with that name. (-48)
java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 1 command [[osascript, /var/folders/z5/n802xjnx49l4535kq63992280000gn/T/fxbundler8419176091447096668/macosx/DMSLauncher-dmg-setup.scpt] in unspecified directory
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:165)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacDmgBundler.buildDMG(MacDmgBundler.java:376)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacDmgBundler.bundle(MacDmgBundler.java:92)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacDmgBundler.execute(MacDmgBundler.java:556)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.Main.main(Main.java:476)
  Config files are saved to /var/folders/z5/n802xjnx49l4535kq63992280000gn/T/fxbundler8419176091447096668/macosx. Use them to customize package.
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerException: Error: Bundler "DMG Installer" (dmg) failed to produce a bundle.
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.Main.main(Main.java:476)
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I went to the file that it said it was having a problem with (DMSLauncher-dmg-setup.scpt) and when I ran the script manually this is what it said:

[image]

Can anyone assist me in fixing this problem? Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? I'm also facing the same issue :s

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still sees the problem, what I did to resolve it was to check /Volumes folder and eject the volume. Here the volume would be 'DMSLauncher'.